# Can JSON for Python Encode/decode functions from text files?

Tags: python, json

I know that JSON is good for encoding/decoding complex data to/from text files, but can it also encode/decode functions to/from files?

Comment: Why don't you put the functions in a `.py` file and `import` them?

Comment: Or use [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)? (note: the safety concerns raised by @F.X. are the same)

Comment: Oops, should have read the whole description of `pickle` first, it doesn't store the function itself, only a reference.

Comment: If you're fine with their security implications, `pickle` or a regular Python modules are indeed much better solutions than JSON ; the first was used by Celery before the current versions, the second is what Django uses to store web app configurations.

Comment: JSON doesn't decode anything.  It is merely notation.  JavaScript Object Notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) or [exec](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#exec) and store your functions as plain text :

```
>>> exec(compile("def f(a):\n  print(a)", "exec", "exec"))
>>> f(2)
2
```

Let me stress, however, that executing code from an untrusted source like a JSON file seems like a *big red warning flag*. It's tricky to get right without risking giving anyone with access to your JSON file access to everything else, and even then there's plenty of better ways to do it.

If you don't require being able to execute *arbitrary* code, a better way would be the way [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) stores its tasks : store the name of the function and its arguments in JSON. You can then check if the function is allowed to be executed, and pass arguments to it. You're still vulnerable if your functions are badly designed, but much less than with arbitrary code.

First, define the function :

```
>>> def f(a):
...     print(a)
```

Store and retrieve a JSON with the name and arguments :

```
>>> json_data = {"name": "f", "args": ["hello world"]}
```

Check that we're allowed to execute this :

```
>>> if json_data["name"] not in ["f"]:
...     raise Exception("forbidden function!")
```

Retrieve and execute the function :

```
>>> json_func = globals(json_data["name"])
>>> json_func(*json_data["args"])
hello world
```

Comment: If any [ast.literaleval()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) will be safer.

Comment: So would it be better to hard code the functions a leave the large text part in a JSON file?

Comment: @KobiK: Oh, this one is neat, I had never heard of it! Thanks ;)

Comment: @Shadowhawk: Definitely. In addition to being safer, it's also much easier to debug and to reason with. I used to `eval` some configuration values in a project at its early stages, which was a nightmare to debug in some corner cases. I quite quickly decided never to do that again.